# Huge ammount of errors during compilation of program with Magick++

Tags: c++, imagemagick, magick++

During the compilation of a program I was making, that uses the Magick++ library, there appeared an incredibily huge ammount of errors.

This is the command line I used for compile it (g++'s version is 4.9.2, running on Ubuntu 12.04):

```
g++ -std=c++14 -g -fopenmp `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags` main.cpp -o glitch_img2 `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
```

Here is the program's code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#ifdef __OPENMP
    #include <omp.h>
#endif
#include <Magick++.h>

double d_max(double a,double b)
{
    return (a>b) ? a : b;
}

int ui_clip(int x,int a,int b)
{
    return (x<b) ? b : ((x>a) ? a : x);
}

int transform(int x)
{
    return ((x*32+1654)%21+x*11+642)%164%33%16;
}

using namespace std;
using namespace Magick;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    Image img1;
    img1.read(argv[1]);

    int size_x = img1.columns();
    int size_y = img1.rows();
    int np = size_x*size_y;
    Image out;
    out.size(Geometry(size_x,size_y));
    double *buff_img1 = new double[3*size_x*size_y];
    double *buff_out  = new double[3*size_x*size_y];

    img1.write(0,0,size_x,size_y,"RGB",DoublePixel,buff_img1);

    int ix, iy;
#ifdef __OPENMP
    #pragma omp for private(ix,iy) schedule(static)
#endif
    for (iy=0;iy<size_y;iy++)
    {
        for (ix=0;ix<size_x;ix++)
        {
            int loc = (size_x*iy+ix)*3;
            double pimg1[3] = {
                buff_img1[3*loc  ],
                buff_img1[3*loc+1],
                buff_img1[3*loc+2]
            };
            int x1 = (ix*(1+transform(ix)))%size_x;
            int y1 = (iy*(1+transform(iy)))%size_y;
            int loc1 = ui_clip((size_x*y1+x1)%np,0,np-1)*3;
            double out_pix[3] = {
                buff_img1[3*loc1  ],
                buff_img1[3*loc1+1],
                buff_img1[3*loc1+2]
            };
            buff_out[3*loc  ] = abs(out_pix[0]-pimg1[0]);
            buff_out[3*loc+1] = abs(out_pix[1]-pimg1[1]);
            buff_out[3*loc+2] = abs(out_pix[2]-pimg1[2]);
        }
    }
    out.read(size_x,size_y,"RGB",DoublePixel,buff_out);
    out.write("Output.png");
}
```

And those errors [are posted here](https://gist.github.com/cynodelic/de36846e2233261a5b0bbf5ce9c1020b).

What causes such errors and how can they be fixed?

---

**EDIT**: The mentioned behaviour dissapears when I remove the `Magick++.h` header.

Comment: Start removing code until the error goes away then add code until it comes back. Keep doing this until you know exactly what line has offended the compiler so greatly. You may find you are trying to stuff the wrong type of data int an Image Magick function call. Sadly I don't know Image Magick from a hole in the ground so I can't give you any better hints than that. Narrow the problem down to an [mcve] and if that doesn't make the problem obvious to you, it probably will for someone here.

Comment: Try `-std=c++11`. It doesn't look like your need any experimental features included in `c++14`.

Comment: @emcconville Even with `-std=c++11`, it gets the same errors.

Comment: And if you remove the OpenMP aspects instead?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did it, and it doesn't work too.